# Capture [A-Z0-9]{6} - but only if it's not \d{6}

Tags: regex, vba, outlook

I have an e-Mail with some 11-digits long numbers - that one's easy: `\d{11}`.

There are also "words" that are 6 characters long.
The Letters there are always uppercase.
It may contain 1-5 Numbers, but never 6. It never extends the size of 6.

```
\b(\d{11}|([A-Z0-9]{6}))(\s|\.|$)
```

also captures e.g. "123456" which I'd like to omit.

It's within an e-Mail, so I'm using VBA with it's "Microsoft VBScript Regular Expression 5.5"-Library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are after:

```
\b(?:\d{11}|(?!\d{6})[A-Z\d]{6})\b
```

See an online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/qnA3ya/1)

- `\b` - Word boundary.
- `(?:` - Open non-capture group:

  - `d{11}` - Eleven numbers.
  - `|` - Or:
  - `(?!\d{6})` - Negative lookahead for 6 numbers.
  - `[A-Z\d]{6}` - Exactly six uppercase letters or digits.
  - `)` - Close non-capture group.
- `\b` - Word boundary.

Answer (score 2):

You may use this regex:

```sh
\b(?:\d{11}|(?=\d{0,5}[A-Z])[A-Z0-9]{6})(?:[\s\.]|$)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/xleMnB/1)

`(?=\d{0,5}[A-Z])` is a positive lookahead that asserts presence of an uppercase letter after 0 to 5 digits thus failing the match when there are 6 digits in 2nd alternation option.